# How can I transfer files from storage bucket to remote server in java

Tags: google-cloud-platform, sftp, jsch

Instead of my local directory I want to transfer files from storage bucket GCP to remote server through SFTP in java using JSch or script .

```
     try{   
            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            jsch.addIdentity(privateSftpKey);
            session = jsch.getSession(SFTPUSER, SFTPHOST, SFTPPORT);
            java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setConfig(config);
            session.connect();
            log.info("Host connected.");
            
            channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
            channel.connect();
            log.info("sftp channel opened and connected.");
            
            channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
            String sftpDirectory = "/home/share";

            File directory = new File("C:\\Users\\XYZ\\Desktop\\Learning\\Projects\\TransferStorageBucketToRemoteServer");
            File[] fList = directory.listFiles();

            for (File file : fList){           
                if (file.isFile()){
                    String filename=file.getAbsolutePath();
                    channelSftp.put(filename, sftpDirectory, ChannelSftp.OVERWRITE);
                    System.out.println(filename + " transferred to " + sftpDirectory );
                }
            }
            log.info("File transfered successfully to host.");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.info("Exception found while tranfer the response.");
            log.info("Exception Message...: {}",ex.getMessage());
        }
```

When I search in internet there is only transferring files from

1. Storage bucket to another storage bucket or
2. Storage bucket to local directory and vise versa

google cloud storage API code , Reading files from storage bucket

```
Credentials credentials = GoogleCredentials
                  .fromStream(new FileInputStream(jsonKey));

 Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(credentials)
                  .setProjectId("projectId").build().getService();

Blob blob = storage.get("bucket-name", "file.txt");
ReadChannel readChannel = blob.reader();
```

But not sure how to upload it in SFTP channel from directly GCP ReadChannel without writing it to another output file and then transferring it in SFTP channel

```
channelSftp.put(file_from_readChannel , sftpDirectory, ChannelSftp.OVERWRITE);
```

But I can't see transferring from storage bucket directly to Remote server .

Can any one assist on this and the possible way of doing it in either java or commands?

Comment: What's your problem? you can't directly transfer from GCS to SFTP. You have to code something, like your code, but instead of using File API you have to use the Google Cloud Storage API, that's all.

Comment: Thanks @guillaumeblaquiere I have tried storage API  but stuck at channelSftp.put(file_from_readChannel , sftpDirectory, ChannelSftp.OVERWRITE); I have edited and added piece of code above in question for reference .

Comment: There is no direct communication between GCS and SFTP. The byte (at least in stream) have to passe by your app, like a proxy. Reading in streaming prevent you to store a file locally, but there is no checksum performed.

Comment: where is this java code running? if it is running on an envirorment you have access to OS you can mount the bucket with gcsfuse and transfer as if it was a local file to a remote sftp.

Comment: @JoséSoní My application would be running in  Kubernetes , where I need to transfer files from Kubernetes (either Storage bucket or some storage independent of the pods running ) to a Remote server daily .

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Thanks , from Read Channel converting into Streams and then passing to SFTP would work .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is running on Kubernetes a posible way to do it for you can be to have the bucket mounted as a drive on the pod, and upload the files to the the FTP server as if they were local files.

To mount the bucket as a drive on the pod ypu can use GCS fuse, [here](https://github.com/maciekrb/gcs-fuse-sample) is an example.

This can be achieved by adding this on the Dockerfile:

**Dockerfile**

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    gnupg \
  && echo "deb http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt $GCSFUSE_REPO main" \
    | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gcsfuse.list \
  && curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add - \
  && apt-get update \
  && apt-get install --yes gcsfuse \
  && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* 

RUN mkdir <MOUNTING_POINT>
RUN gcsfuse -o nonempty <BUCKET_NAME> <MOUNTING_POINT>
```

Once it is mounted you will be able to [upload the files to the SFTP](https://www.baeldung.com/java-file-sftp#2-setting-up-jsch) as if they were local files.

Comment: Soni  Thanks, gcsfuse way is better for storage bucket and fine to mount every time a image is created but is there a way to access my files stored outside my pods (independent of pods) ?

Comment: what are you refering to? are you refering to mount this directly at the task level?